# how to replace shortened 'str' and 'av' in 1 column in sql?

Tags: sql, string, replace, substring

the sql table has addresses with 'str' and 'av' shortened names.
I need to make it full like 'street' , 'avenue'

```
Jacob str. 34
5th av.
wall str.67
```

I need to use 'replace' function, but it does not change the 'av' if i only can specify 1 placeholder for str.:

```
select 
replace(address, 'str.' , 'street' )  as e

from store_address
```

how to change the 'av'  part? the resulting column should include both.

Comment: Tag your database. You can nest `replace` function.

Comment: This will end in tears. I promise.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn, why may i ask?

Comment: Google for "falsehoods programmers believe about addresses". You'll have things like streets where name ends with the character "street", or where Str is legitimately the only correct way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `replace()` twice:

```
select replace(replace(address, 'str.' , 'street'), 'av.', 'avenue')  as e
from store_address
```